# How to get @ViewScoped bean property in CSS resource?

Tags: css, jsf, el, view-scope

I have a `@ViewScoped` bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class testBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String color;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        color = "red";
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

In my JSF page I can access the property color by `#{testBean.color}`, but in my CSS resource it doesn't work.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    background-color: #{testBean.color};
}
```

It throws the below exception:

```
org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.view.ViewScoped
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:680) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:79) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:78) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at com.unifik.core.subdomain.admin.WidgetLoginBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getWidgetLogin(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    ... 46 more
```

If I change `@ViewScoped` to `@SessionScoped`, then it works, but I do not want that.

Comment: Why don't you want to use <h:outputStylesheet name="css/color.css" /> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bean cannot be view scoped for that. The CSS file is requested during a completely separate GET request initiated by the webbrowser when it's being instructed to download the CSS file after inspecting the retrieved HTML page. This specific request for the CSS file knows nothing about the JSF view state and hence any EL expressions referencing a JSF view scoped bean just won't be able to find the desired bean as there's no means of a JSF view state anywhere during processing the request for the CSS file.

Either choose another bean scope, or inline it in a `<style>` element in the HTML page. A request, session or application scoped bean should work. See also [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

Comment: Thank you very much, suspected the answer, but still create a session bean is not good for that, the best approach is to let the styles in the xhtml (I think) and whether it is better practice to use `<h: outputStylesheet />`, it would be good to have a better alternative

Answer (score -2):

I did this in my CSS file and is working:

```
.color {color: #{initParam['icons_color']} !important;}
a.color {color: #{initParam['icons_color']} !important;}
a.color:hover, a.color:focus {color: #1faabe;}
.bg-color {
     background-color: #{initParam['icons_color']} !important;
}
```

You can use context parameters if is necessary one for session or something like that.

For this works the CSS must be put in page using the tag h:outputStylesheet like:
       `<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="my.css">`

I tried to use like this:
      `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="settings.css" />`
And does not work.

Comment: does it work? Encounter any problems? If the answers are 'yes' and 'no' it is fine to use (but I think this should be a new question!)

Comment: Kukeltje is not a question, is a possible answer to change the managed bean for a initparameter, but I just tried to do this now and is fine until now.

Comment: Sorry, you're not answering the concrete question about a `@ViewScoped` bean not being referencable in a CSS resource.